# Javascript google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have multiple locations of my company's regional offices and have to show each location whenever user clicks at a locations like:

location1
location2
location3

When user clicks at location 1 it will show location 1 on the map. I also have those locations in my maps. I have never worked with Google maps before, so I just need some idea to get started.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about it just about to do it now thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your user clicks a link, run a piece a javascript that calls [setCenter(latlng:LatLng)](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Map) on the map to center the map to a certain location.

If you really don't know where to begin, then start by reading the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html) documentation. It's easy to read, and it contains lots of working [examples](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this: (I'm sure it could be optimized with a for loop, its early/late right now.

```
  <html>
    <head>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function initialize() { //Initalize JS after onload
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), { 
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    });


    var randomPoint1 = new google.maps.LatLng(44.6479, -63.5744); //First Location

    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({ //Set up marker
           position: randomPoint1,
           map: map
        });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('locationid1'), 'click', //Set up DOM listener 1
        function(){
            map.setZoom(13);
         map.setCenter(marker1.getPosition());  
        });


    var randomPoint2 = new google.maps.LatLng(45.5081, -73.5550); //Second Location

    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: randomPoint2,
           map: map
        });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('locationid2'), 'click',//Set up DOM listener 2
        function(){
            map.setZoom(13);
         map.setCenter(marker2.getPosition());  
        });


    var randomPoint3 = new google.maps.LatLng(43.6481, -79.4042); //Third Location

    var marker3 = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: randomPoint3,
           map: map
        });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('locationid3'), 'click', //Set up DOM listener 3
        function(){
            map.setZoom(13);
         map.setCenter(marker3.getPosition());  
        });
        map.setCenter(marker2.getPosition());
        map.setZoom(5);
    }



    </script>

    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()"> <!--Initalize JS after onload--->
        <a href="#" id="locationid1">Halifax</a>
        <a href="#" id="locationid2">Montreal</a>
        <a href="#" id="locationid3">Toronto</a>

        <div id="map_canvas" style="height:100%; width:100%"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

And after I write this I realize the post was from last August. Oh well, may help someone at some point.

Comment: You shouldn't need to repeat similar operations explicitly. [Here's an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map2.html) which uses a function for creating markers (and sidebar entries, which might also be useful).